# Angular4 and Bootstrap 4 navbar inline-block not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

As I write in the title, I tried to pass from Bootstrap 3 to 4 and after my update, my navbar was broken :

[image]

I did nothing wrong and i really can't understand why the inline-block is not working anymore. I tried every thing I found on stackOverflow about this subject and nothing happenned..

Here is my HTML code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="center-block text-center">
   <button  class="collapse-btn" (click)="toggleMenu()">
     <i *ngIf="!isCollapsed()" class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <i *ngIf="isCollapsed()" class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Progression</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Activité pédagogique</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Evalutation</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Synthèse</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Certification</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your CSS, which is lacking in the question, add `display:inline-block;` to `.nav-item` class.
If not working, see what's overriding your deceleration using dev-tools for example.

Comment: This is not working ! Thats why I asked for it...

Comment: I think is < ul class="nav" >, NOT <ul class="nav-bar nav">

Comment: Not for bootstrap 4 ! I tried every css tricks but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it seems that i needed to change property display for navbar-nav from inline-block to flex.

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: change the class of ul. MUST be <ul class="nav-bar nav"> (you have navbar-nav).  Anyway, What are you using? bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, some diferent?